# function inside while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What Im trying to do is to get the content of a specific textarea tag in a specific clicks of a button, so I think a loop will solve this problem. The while loop on PHP does the role of making the name of textarea different and button's onclick trigger. But the loop in javascript wont work. Please anyone help what is the right one to complete my task?? Sorry for bad english...Thanks in advance

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>

    var i = 0;

    while(i < 2000)
    {
        i++;

        function feedbacks+i()
        {
         var feed = document.getElementsByName("feedback"+i)[0].value;
         alert(feed);
        }
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

    while($i < 2000)

    $i++;
    echo "<textarea name='feedback$i' >you post</textarea>";
    echo "<button onclick='feedbacks$i()' >send feedback</button>";

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you need a page with 2000 text areas? Just wondering.

Comment: I think what you want is ONE function that takes an argument, not 2000 functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if i get your question right, but why don't you write one single javascript function and pass the index as a parameter?
like:

```
function feedbacks(index) {
    var feed = document.getElementsByName("feedback"+index)[0].value;
    alert(feed);
}
```

and

```
onclick='feedbacks($i)'
```

Comment: I got it!!! Thank you sir for this wonderful answer.

I really appreciated you for correcting my works. I'm just a beginner in javascript so please be patient to me :) Please if I can have your time. Please visit my other questions 'coz there's more. I'm having fun writing codes for our projects and I highly appreciated if I have you answers. God bless :D

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incorrect, Since you have tagged your question with Jquery, I would like to suggest the following solution,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click','button',function(){
     alert($(this).prev('textarea').val())
   });
});
```

You are creating those elements `textarea` and the `button` in runtime, So you have to use delegation inorder to register the click event for those buttons. Additionally you have to wrap your code inside `.ready()` function, Which means you have to manipulate the DOM only after it got ready.

Please see here for references,

- [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (for delegation)
- [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: That's my first option to do this thing sir. But unfortunately, for some reason, I don't know. But whenever I retrieve some page containing data from database with buttons or textarea, I couldn't perform jQuery codes well.

But I really appreciated you for correcting my works. I'm just a beginner in javascript so please be patient to me :) Please if I can have your time. Please visit my other questions 'coz there's more. I'm having fun writing codes for our projects and I highly appreciated if I have you answers. God bless :D

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems here.

---

*Naming your function*

When you name a function, you can't use variables, only a single identifier.

You could use a function expression and then assign the result somewhat that you can identify with a variable. e.g.

```
an_array_i_created_earlier[i] = function () {
    // etc etc
}
```

---

*Closures*

You are trying to use `i` inside the function you are creating, but you are changing it outside that function before that function runs.

You can get around this by creating a new closure.

```
function createFunction(i) {
    return function () {
       // can use i sanely here because it was passed into a local variable belonging to `createFunction`
    };
}

an_array_i_created_earlier[i] = createFunction(i);
```

---

This is all very messy though. You can forget about having to deal with `i` entirely, and throw out the horribly intrinsic event attributes while you are at it. Instead, navigate through the DOM to find the element:

```
addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var textarea, t = evt.target; 
    if (t.classList.contains('feedback')) {
        textarea = t.previousElementSibling;
        alert(textarea.value);
    }
});
```

Note that this uses some fairly recent additions to browser DOM. If you want compatibility with older browsers (in particular IE9 and earlier) then you will probably want to rewrite it to add some support for legacy approaches. A library like YUI or jQuery can help with that.

Comment: Your explanation is awesome!!! I can get the point but can't totally understand the logic sir. Please I want to know more.
I really appreciated you for correcting my works. I'm just a beginner in javascript so please be patient to me :) Please if I can have your time. Please visit my other questions 'coz there's more. I'm having fun writing codes for our projects and I highly appreciated if I have you answers. God bless :D

Answer (score -1):

There's some error in your JavaScript code:

1. <del>You tried to define a sequence of functions in a loop, and the function became local function to that loop. You cannot get access to these functions outside the loop. In order to make this work, you should define the function on `window` object, with the syntax `window["feedbacks1"] = function () {}`</del>.
2. `function feedbacks+i()` is invalid syntax, use `window['feedbacks' + i]`, as pointed in (1).
3. Functions defined in loop will share some local variable (closure). The variable in the function `feedbacks#{i}` will all share the same `i`. After the loop, `i` became `2001` and all the functions defined will try to get textarea with name `feedbacks2001`, which of course will not work. You will need the `(function (i) { /* the code using i */ })(i);` trick to make a local copy of the shared variable.

I made [**a demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2rHE2/) which correct the mistakes. I showed only 2 textareas. The following javascript should work for you 2000 textareas case.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) {
    window["feedbacks" + i] = (function (i) {
        return function (e) {
            var feed = document.getElementsByName("feedback"+i)[0].value;
            alert(feed);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Point #1 is wrong.  Javascript has only function scope, not block scope so a function defined in a loop is the same as a function defined at the top of the containing function or containing scope.   Also, I think a better solution would be ONE function that takes an argument rather than a bunch of nearly identical functions.

Comment: I guest you guys're right. hehe sorry for lack of knowledge.

I really appreciated you for correcting my works. I'm just a beginner in javascript so please be patient to me :) Please if I can have your time. Please visit my other questions 'coz there's more. I'm having fun writing codes for our projects and I highly appreciated if I have you answers. God bless :D